# If $A$ is a noncommutative unital ring and $S = A \setminus \{0\},$ when is $S^{-1}A$ a division ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noncommutative-algebra, localization

Suppose $A$ is a domain and $S=A \setminus \{0\}$ is a left denominator set. I have the following argument:

> Let $\phi \colon A \to S^{-1}A$ be the natural map to the ring of fractions. Then I know that $S^{-1}A = \{ \phi(s)^{-1}\phi(a) : s\in S, a\in A \}.$ Now suppose $\phi(s)^{-1}\phi(a)$ is a nonzero element in $S^{-1}A.$ Then $a$ is nonzero (if it were, we would have $\phi(a) = 0,$ hence $\phi(s)^{-1}\phi(a) = 0)$, so $a \in S = A \setminus \{0\}.$ Then $\phi(a)^{-1}\phi(s)$ is an inverse of $\phi(s)^{-1}\phi(a).$

Does this mean that $S^{-1}A$ is always a division ring whenever $S = A \setminus \{0\}$ is left localisable? This doesn't seem right to me, but I can't find what I got wrong in my reasoning. Could somebody please help?

EDIT: The reason I ask this is that I have the following theorem in my notes: every Noetherian domain has a division ring of fractions. It is proved as follows:

> Let $S = A \setminus \{0\}$, which is a left Ore set. It consists of regular elements because $A$ is a domain. Therefore, the natural map $\phi \colon A \to S^{-1}A$ is injective, and $S^{-1}A = \{s^{-1}a : s\in S,a\in A\}.$ Now if $s^{-1}a \in S^{-1}A$ is nonzero, then $a,s \in S,$ and $a^{-1}s$ is the inverse of $s^{-1}x$.

However, by my reasoning above, I don't understand why we need injectivity in the proof. It feels like we only need to know the existence of the left quotient ring of $A$ with respect to $S$.

Comment: Do you mean that $A\setminus\{0\}$ is a left denominator set? or "left-Ore set" or something like that? What does it mean?

Comment: @rschwieb Ah yes, I mean $A \setminus\{0\}$ is a left-denominator set.

Comment: The only concern could be that $S^{-1}A$ collapses to zero. If it doesn't everything that's nonzero has an inverse.

Comment: Yeah I noticed this too. I supposed that the reason we wanted injectivity is that it is a true division ring of ‘fractions’ since $A$ embeds in $S^{-1}A$.